# How to install bootstrap extension in yii

Tags: yii

Im a newbie to yii and have been trying to add bootstrap and giiplus extension to yii.However after adding the extracted file to extensions folder and making changes in main.php I cant seem to get error in displaying even the main page.I followed this tutorial..

http://www.cniska.net/yii-bootstrap/setup.html

Comment: after i used bootstrap generator in yii using gii the error was from CActiveForm.

Answer (score 7):

Download extension from [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/bootstrap/).

Paste all bootstrap extensions folders what you have download under extensions/bootstrap

## config/main.php

Add before starting of array 
 `Yii::setPathOfAlias('bootstrap', dirname(__FILE__).'/../extensions/bootstrap');`

Add under return array

```
'theme'=>'bootstrap',
    'modules'=>array(
        'gii'=>array(
            'generatorPaths'=>array(
                'bootstrap.gii',
            ),                      
        ),
    ),
```

Add in under components

```
        'bootstrap'=>array(
        'class'=>'bootstrap.components.Bootstrap',
         ),
```

## extensions/boostrap/components/Bootstrap.php

Paste code in class

```
public function init() {
    $this->registerAllCss();
    $this->registerJs();
    parent::init();
}
```

## protected/views/layout/main.php

Paste the line under head tag

```
<?php echo Yii::app()->bootstrap->init();?>
```

## Follow this link for documentation

http://www.cniska.net/yii-bootstrap/

Comment: <pre>'theme'=>'bootstrap',
    'modules'=>array(
        'gii'=>array(
            'generatorPaths'=>array(
                'bootstrap.gii',
            ),                      
        ),
    ),
</pre>

Comment: 'theme' => 'bootstrap',
    'modules' => array(
        'gii' => array(
            'class' => 'system.gii.GiiModule',
            'password' => 'admin',
            'generatorPaths' => array(
                'bootstrap.gii',
            ),
        ),
    ),

Comment: You can use this one http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-bootstrap3-module/