# Yii with Bootstrap error (CWebApplication.bootstrap not defined)

Tags: yii

I have followed this setup, but not work for me http://www.cniska.net/yii-bootstrap/setup.html, all CSS files do not give style to the page,

So searching I found this thread [How to install bootstrap extension in yii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13286239/how-to-install-bootstrap-extension-in-yii/16565170#16565170) using some tricks. But not work's too.

Now I have this error
'Property "CWebApplication.bootstrap" is not defined.'

Anyone can help or have any idea?
Thanks in advance and for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Property "CWebApplication.bootstrap" is not defined.

The error means the system is trying to access Yii::app()->bootstrap, which could be a property on the application. Since bootstrap is a component it should be accessible, if the configuration is done properly.

This error is most likely because you forgot the following in the main config file:

```
'components'=>array(
    'bootstrap'=>array(
        'class'=>'bootstrap.components.Bootstrap', 
    ),
),
```

// This should point to the location you placed the files in for example extensions/bootstrap/components/bootstrap.php

The class location above will only work if the alias is set properly before setting the configuration.

```
Yii::setPathOfAlias('bootstrap', dirname(__FILE__).'/../extensions/bootstrap');
```

Instead you could also change "bootstrap.components.Bootstrap" into "application.extensions.bootstrap.components.bootstrap".

Answer (score 0):

I strongly advise you to use Yiistrap, it was made by the person who create yii boostrap and the person who created Yiibooster. Yiistrap has everything from both extensions and more new stuff. here is the page http://www.getyiistrap.com , also has a fully documented API which yii boostrap do not have and it will save a lot of google searches.

Comment: I'm trying use now, but... no success... I get another error
_Alias "bootstrap.components.TbApi" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing PHP file and the file is readable._
I check the permissions but everything look's fine.

Comment: you might want to check inside the tbapi class , I think I had to change an include path at the top of this class because by default it was pointing to a wrong location.