# Yii - syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')' in

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii, twitter-bootstrap-3

I was following this answer on how to install Bootstrap on Yii Framework... https://stackoverflow.com/a/16565170

But I get an error on my site when trying to access it saying this:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')' in C:\wamp\www\yii\yii\protected\config\main.php on line 101
```

here is my code for where the error is supposed to be

```
    // application-level parameters that can be accessed
    // using Yii::app()->params['paramName']
    'params'=>array(
        // this is used in contact page
        'adminEmail'=>'webmaster@example.com',
    ),

    'bootstrap' => array(
            'class' => 'bootstrap.components.TbApi',   
        ),
    )
);
```

Here is my full config file:

```
<?php

// uncomment the following to define a path alias
// Yii::setPathOfAlias('local','path/to/local-folder');

// This is the main Web application configuration. Any writable
// CWebApplication properties can be configured here.
return array(
    'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
    'name'=>'DJCDev',

    // preloading 'log' component
    'preload'=>array('log'),

    // autoloading model and component classes
    'import'=>array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
         'bootstrap.helpers.TbHtml',
    ),

    'aliases' => array(
        'bootstrap' => realpath(__DIR__ . '/../extensions/bootstrap'), // change this if necessary

    'modules'=>array(
        // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool
        /*
        'gii'=>array(
            'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
            'password'=>'Enter Your Password Here',
            // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
            'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
        ),
        */
        'gii' => array(
            'generatorPaths' => array('bootstrap.gii'),
        ),

    // application components
    'components'=>array(
        'user'=>array(
            // enable cookie-based authentication
            'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
        ),
        // uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format
        /*
        'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'rules'=>array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ),
        */
        'db'=>array(
            'connectionString' => 'sqlite:'.dirname(__FILE__).'/../data/testdrive.db',
        ),
        // uncomment the following to use a MySQL database
        /*
        'db'=>array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdrive',
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ),
        */
        'errorHandler'=>array(
            // use 'site/error' action to display errors
            'errorAction'=>'site/error',
        ),
        'log'=>array(
            'class'=>'CLogRouter',
            'routes'=>array(
                array(
                    'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                    'levels'=>'error, warning',
                ),
                // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages
                /*
                array(
                    'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
                ),
                */
            ),
        ),
    ),

    // application-level parameters that can be accessed
    // using Yii::app()->params['paramName']
    'params'=>array(
        // this is used in contact page
        'adminEmail'=>'webmaster@example.com',
    ),

    'bootstrap' => array(
            'class' => 'bootstrap.components.TbApi',   
        ),
    )
    );
```

Ive edited my code and I get a different error now

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''aliases'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in C:\wamp\www\yii\yii\protected\config\main.php on line 12
```

My config file now:

```
<?php

// uncomment the following to define a path alias
// Yii::setPathOfAlias('local','path/to/local-folder');

// This is the main Web application configuration. Any writable
// CWebApplication properties can be configured here.
return array(
    'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
    'name'=>'DJCDev',
    )
    'aliases' => array(
        'bootstrap' => realpath(__DIR__ . '/../extensions/bootstrap'), // change this if necessary
    ),
    // preloading 'log' component
    'preload'=>array('log'),

    // autoloading model and component classes
    'import'=>array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
        'bootstrap.helpers.TbHtml',
    ),

    'modules'=>array(
        'gii' => array(
            'generatorPaths' => array('bootstrap.gii'),
        ),
        // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool
        /*
        'gii'=>array(
            'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
            'password'=>'Enter Your Password Here',
            // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
            'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
        ),
        */
    ),

    // application components
    'components'=>array(
        'user'=>array(
            // enable cookie-based authentication
            'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
        ),
        // uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format
        /*
        'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'rules'=>array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ),
        */
        'db'=>array(
            'connectionString' => 'sqlite:'.dirname(__FILE__).'/../data/testdrive.db',
        ),
        // uncomment the following to use a MySQL database
        /*
        'db'=>array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdrive',
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ),
        */
        'errorHandler'=>array(
            // use 'site/error' action to display errors
            'errorAction'=>'site/error',
        ),
        'log'=>array(
            'class'=>'CLogRouter',
            'routes'=>array(
                array(
                    'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                    'levels'=>'error, warning',
                ),
                // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages
                /*
                array(
                    'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
                ),
                */
            ),
        ),
        'bootstrap' => array(
            'class' => 'bootstrap.components.TbApi',   
        ),
    ),

    // application-level parameters that can be accessed
    // using Yii::app()->params['paramName']
    'params'=>array(
        // this is used in contact page
        'adminEmail'=>'webmaster@example.com',
    ),
);
```

Comment: Please post from start of the config file. Here you have two extra closing brackets ')'

Comment: Triple check your brackets. You probably have one less than needed.

Comment: Added full config and its still the same when I take a bracket away, nothing changes

Comment: I think you're missing a closing ) in modules.

Comment: You now have an extra `),` before aliases.

Comment: I just edited that, I noticed it after I added the config file to the question, I still get the error

Comment: @DaleChad Are you sure you removed the `)` before aliases? Without that I get no error: http://codepad.org/YxtDCEy0

Comment: @Jim the error has been solved, meda solved it, I didnt have the 'aliases' in an array which gave me the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please indent your code properly to avoid such mistake, remove extra commas and parenthese:

```
array(
      //.......
      'params'=>array(
             'adminEmail'=>'webmaster@example.com'
      ),

      'bootstrap' => array(
             'class' => 'bootstrap.components.TbApi'
      )
);
```

**full code:**

```
<?php
return array(
    'basePath' => dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..',
    'name' => 'DJCDev',

    // preloading 'log' component

    'preload' => array(
        'log'
    ) ,

    // autoloading model and component classes

    'import' => array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
        'bootstrap.helpers.TbHtml',
    ) ,
    'aliases' => array(
        'bootstrap' => realpath(__DIR__ . '/../extensions/bootstrap') , // change this if necessary
        'modules' => array(

            // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool

            'gii' => array(
                'generatorPaths' => array(
                    'bootstrap.gii'
                ) ,
            ) ,

            // application components

            'components' => array(
                'user' => array(

                    // enable cookie-based authentication

                    'allowAutoLogin' => true,
                ) ,

                // uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format

                'db' => array(
                    'connectionString' => 'sqlite:' . dirname(__FILE__) . '/../data/testdrive.db',
                ) ,

                // uncomment the following to use a MySQL database

                'errorHandler' => array(

                    // use 'site/error' action to display errors

                    'errorAction' => 'site/error',
                ) ,
                'log' => array(
                    'class' => 'CLogRouter',
                    'routes' => array(
                        array(
                            'class' => 'CFileLogRoute',
                            'levels' => 'error, warning',
                        ) ,
                    ) ,
                ) ,
            ) ,

            // application-level parameters that can be accessed
            // using Yii::app()->params['paramName']

            'params' => array(

                // this is used in contact page

                'adminEmail' => 'webmaster@example.com',
            ) ,
            'bootstrap' => array(
                'class' => 'bootstrap.components.TbApi',
            ) ,
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Its still not worked, I'll make sure that I have the layout correct and that it matches and check all of my opening and closing brackets

Comment: look again by the `bootstrap` there is an extra bracket `),));`

Comment: `aliases` and `modules` are "not closed" too. The indentation is just too ugly.  For sure,  it's a bracket missing. Moreover you can use an IDE to have a better idea of where is the error.

Comment: Ive edited my config file (shown in question) and I get a different error, I have fixed the aliases and modules also

Comment: @DaleChad now alias is not part of any array `return array(...),'aliases'`

Comment: @meda Thank you for noticing, It has solved my error and is now successfully working